# AnkiDroid doesn't detect apkg file in the requested location

Tags: ankidroid

I have Android 4.1.1 and my AnkiDroid version is 2.3.2. I have downloaded a deck (`.apkg` file) and I would like to import it into AnkiDroid, which requires me to place the file into a specified folder `/storage/sdcard0/AnkiDroid`.

Oddly enough, the AnkiDroid folder didn't yet exist, so I went on and created it, paying attention to the proper 'CamelCase' in the name of the folder. I have copied the `.apkg` to this folder but I cannot import it because AnkiDroid cannot find the `.apkg` in that folder.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't have had to make that folder, it's not possible for it to not exist if you can use AnkiDroid. What value do you see under `settings>AnkiDroid>Collection path`? There should be a file called `collection.anki2` in the AnkiDroid folder.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it should be seen in the Import dialog. Please fill a bug report at https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues thanks!

Meanwhile, you can use the second method for importing a .apk file:
https://ankidroid.org/docs/manual.html#_open_the_file_using_android
Just install any file explorer (like [File Manager](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=file%20manager&fdid=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ics)), and tap your .apkg file. It will open in AnkiDroid.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i had the same problem before but now i know how to fix it. 
All you need to do is to locate 'ankidroid' folder in your file system, not in storage folder but outside of storage folder then just copy the .apkg files there. No need to make new folder or whatsoever.